# How to go to another activity after execute camera Android Studio

Tags: java, multithreading, android-studio, android-activity, android-camera

I'm trying to go to other activity after execute the camera but, the camera is an activity so, I try to execute StartActivity After this but doesn't work, I've tried using startactivities but neither works. Could you help me please? How can I do this

[This is my try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoW6c.png)

Comment: Please don't post the code as an image. [ask]

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here

Answer (score 0):

you could create a variable to listen when you start camera, then in you onresume of activity, check this variable and start new activity here

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try